# How to use a third party js in Angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I want to use a third party js file (not written in angularjs) as a service in angularjs controller.
I am able to use the js in html inside script> tag but I want to use the functions in controller.
Is there a way to include the js file inside controller as a service or some other way?

Answer (score 3):

you can create a new service in angular like this

```
angular
  .module("app")
        .factory("jsService", function () {
                 // here goes the code of your js (d3 in my case)
                 //now return the object of the service
                 return d3;
         }
```

and then you can inject this service to any controller and use it

**Update : **
click the button and you can log the d3 service ,, and you can use it inside angular ,,

https://jsfiddle.net/rzkku08r/

**Update : **
you can inject jQuery it self as a service ,, and add your plugin to it ,, like what I did with d3 ,, you can see that I added d3 service and before returning I added the code of two plugins (word cloud by Jason Davies)
 and (d3.tip) and then returned the service containing (d3 and plugins) and I can use them every where in my app ,,

Comment: but that would mean rewriting the js code in angularjs syntax? I want to avoid that

Comment: no you don't have to re-write the code ,, I'll put a jsFiddle for you now

Comment: the js depends on jquery (http://codepad.org/I5gvzUfO), how will I be able to access the functions via service

Comment: Thanks, Your Answer help me!